# PHP file size exceeds the limit even though the limits are higher in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, post, file-upload, size

I'm trying to upload a PDF file which is bigger than 200 MB and then convert it to JPEG images in my Amazon Linux server. However, I get the following error before the conversion begins:

```
PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 242679370 bytes exceeds the limit of 209715200 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

I have been looking through previous questions if I miss any setting but all of my limits are higher  than the uploaded file size. Here's what I got in my `php.ini`:

```
max_execution_time = 30000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
upload_max_filesize = 512M
```

I have verified these settings via `phpinfo()`.

I have also increased `KeepAliveTimeout` to 15 in my Apache configuration.

I also made sure that if there's something wrong in my script but it works as expected for files under 200 MB. Any ideas about this problem? Perhaps I am missing something or did not set the related limit correctly.

Comment: May just be as simple as increase `memory_limit = 736M` as once uploaded it need to load it into memory with existing memory requirement. 'max_execution_time = 30000' is ridiculous and irrelevant, so you could put that back to 90 seconds at most.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am aware of the max_execution_time value, however the file is being posted and then getting converted which takes a lot of time, sometimes up to an hour or maybe more. Will try to increase memory limit to 600 MB which is my server's max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my settings were overridden by an `.htaccess` file created by someone else. When working with other people, make sure to check `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 0):

try with ini_set

Add this code to your php code

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '512M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '512M');
```

Comment: Setting the limits in code has no effect, upload happens before it is executed.